# Unexpected Import: Mocha ES6 Node application issue

Tags: node.js, express, ecmascript-6, mocha.js, babeljs

Currently, there is es6 import issue in Mocha test cases. I have tried to add babel and presets latest, but it is not resolving anything. I have tried a couple of available solutions but could not resolve my issue.

This is my package.json `

```
{
  "name": "ep-backend",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "dev": "ts-node-dev --respawn --transpileOnly $NODE_DEBUG_OPTION ./app/app.ts",
    "prod": "tsc && node ./build/app.js",
    "test": "NODE_DEBUG=\"fs\" DEBUG=\"*\" mocha --require @babel/register $(find test -name '*.ts')"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.16.1",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "chai-http": "^4.2.1",
    "dotenv": "^7.0.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "http-status-codes": "^1.3.1",
    "mocha": "^6.0.2",
    "nock": "^10.0.6",
    "ts-node-dev": "^1.0.0-pre.32",
    "typescript": "^3.3.3333"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.0",
    "@babel/register": "^7.4.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-latest": "^6.24.1"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "latest"
    ]
  }
}
```

`
this is my project structure

```
ep-backend -> app -> services -> service.ts
ep-backend -> package.json
ep-backend -> tsconfig.json
ep-backend -> .babelrc
ep-backend -> test -> services -> service.test.ts
```

The content of .babelrc is

```
`{ "presets": ["latest"]}`
```

my tsconfig.json is `

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5", 
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./build",
    "esModuleInterop": true

  }
}
`
```

In my service.test.ts, I'm importing service.ts like

```
import { getAllTests, createTest, getTestByID } from "../../app/services/replicar-service";
```

My console error log is

```
NODE_DEBUG="fs" DEBUG="*" mocha --require @babel/register $(find test -name '*.ts')

  mocha:cli:options no config found in /home/haseeb/workplace/ai.aai.research/EP-2.0/ep-backend/package.json +0ms
  mocha:cli:options No mocha.opts found at ./test/mocha.opts +3ms
  mocha:cli:mocha loaded opts { _: [ 'test/controllers/test-controllers.test.ts' ],
  require: [ '@babel/register' ],
  r: [ '@babel/register' ],
  config: false,
  package: false,
  opts: false,
  diff: true,
  extension: [ 'js' ],
  'watch-extensions': [ 'js' ],
  reporter: 'spec',
  R: 'spec',
  slow: 75,
  s: 75,
  timeout: 2000,
  t: 2000,
  timeouts: 2000,
  ui: 'bdd',
  u: 'bdd' } +0ms
  mocha:cli:mocha final node args {} +2ms
  mocha:cli:mocha exec /home/haseeb/.nvm/versions/node/v10.6.0/bin/node w/ args: [ '/home/haseeb/workplace/ai.aai.research/EP-2.0/ep-backend/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha',
  'test/controllers/test-controllers.test.ts',
  '--require',
  '@babel/register',
  '--no-config',
  '--no-package',
  '--no-opts',
  '--diff',
  '--extension',
  'js',
  '--reporter',
  'spec',
  '--slow',
  '75',
  '--timeout',
  '2000',
  '--ui',
  'bdd' ] +3ms
  mocha:cli:cli entered main with raw args [ 'test/controllers/test-controllers.test.ts',
  '--require',
  '@babel/register',
  '--no-config',
  '--no-package',
  '--no-opts',
  '--diff',
  '--extension',
  'js',
  '--reporter',
  'spec',
  '--slow',
  '75',
  '--timeout',
  '2000',
  '--ui',
  'bdd' ] +0ms
  mocha:cli:run:helpers loaded require "@babel/register" +0ms
  mocha:cli:run post-yargs config { _: [],
  diff: true,
  require: [ '@babel/register' ],
  r: [ '@babel/register' ],
  config: false,
  package: false,
  opts: false,
  extension: [ 'js' ],
  'watch-extensions': [ 'js' ],
  watchExtensions: [ 'js' ],
  reporter: 'spec',
  R: 'spec',
  slow: 75,
  s: 75,
  timeout: 2000,
  t: 2000,
  timeouts: 2000,
  ui: 'bdd',
  u: 'bdd',
  spec: [ 'test/controllers/test-controllers.test.ts' ],
  '$0': 'mocha' } +0ms
  mocha:suite bail undefined +0ms
  mocha:suite slow 75 +0ms
  mocha:suite timeout 2000 +0ms
  mocha:cli:run:helpers files (in order):  [ '/home/haseeb/workplace/ai.aai.research/EP-2.0/ep-backend/test/controllers/test-controllers.test.ts' ] +3ms
  mocha:cli:run running tests with files [ '/home/haseeb/workplace/ai.aai.research/EP-2.0/ep-backend/test/controllers/test-controllers.test.ts' ] +3ms
  babel:config:config-chain Ignored '/home/haseeb/workplace/ai.aai.research/EP-2.0/ep-backend/node_modules/mocha/lib/interfaces/common.js' because it matched one of [ /^\/home\/haseeb\/workplace\/ai\.aai\.research\/EP-2\.0\/ep-backend(?:\/.*)?\/node_modules\//i ] from '/home/haseeb/workplace/ai.aai.research/EP-2.0/ep-backend' +0ms
/home/haseeb/workplace/ai.aai.research/EP-2.0/ep-backend/test/controllers/test-controllers.test.ts:4
 import { getAllTests, createTest, getTestByID } from "../../app/services/replicar-service";
        ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at new Script (vm.js:74:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:246:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:298:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:28)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (/home/haseeb/workplace/ai.aai.research/EP-2.0/ep-backend/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:104:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at /home/haseeb/workplace/ai.aai.research/EP-2.0/ep-backend/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:327:36
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Mocha.loadFiles (/home/haseeb/workplace/ai.aai.research/EP-2.0/ep-backend/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:324:14)
    at Mocha.run (/home/haseeb/workplace/ai.aai.research/EP-2.0/ep-backend/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:801:10)
    at Object.exports.singleRun (/home/haseeb/workplace/ai.aai.research/EP-2.0/ep-backend/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run-helpers.js:207:16)
    at exports.runMocha (/home/haseeb/workplace/ai.aai.research/EP-2.0/ep-backend/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run-helpers.js:300:13)
    at Object.exports.handler.argv [as handler] (/home/haseeb/workplace/ai.aai.research/EP-2.0/ep-backend/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run.js:296:3)
    at Object.runCommand (/home/haseeb/workplace/ai.aai.research/EP-2.0/ep-backend/node_modules/yargs/lib/command.js:238:44)
    at Object.parseArgs [as _parseArgs] (/home/haseeb/workplace/ai.aai.research/EP-2.0/ep-backend/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:1072:28)
    at Object.parse (/home/haseeb/workplace/ai.aai.research/EP-2.0/ep-backend/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:566:25)
    at Object.exports.main (/home/haseeb/workplace/ai.aai.research/EP-2.0/ep-backend/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/cli.js:62:6)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/haseeb/workplace/ai.aai.research/EP-2.0/ep-backend/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:10:23)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:236:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:560:3)
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of `@babel/register`, `.es6, .es, .jsx, .mjs, and .js are the only extensions will be processed by default`. You can override it requiring the module in your test file. Check the following url to see the available options.

https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-register#specifying-options